# Symfony4 QLSTATE[23000]: Duplicate entry problem with logger to database action

Tags: forms, symfony, logging, symfony4

I have application where i have to logg every user action, what URL he visit, if he's acction was successful or no not. So for that i made listener to check every visited URL and LogFactory like this:

```
class UserLogFactory
{
    private $container;
    private $entityManager;
    private $platform;
    private $logRepository;
    private $request;
    private $userLogger;

public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container,
                            EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,
                            UserPlatformChecker $platform,
                            UserLogTypeRepository $logRepository,
                            RequestStack $request,
                            LoggerInterface $userLogger
)
{
    $this->container = $container;
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
    $this->platform = $platform;
    $this->logRepository = $logRepository;
    $this->request = $request;
    $this->userLogger = $userLogger;
}

public function userLogFactory($logType, $logText)
{
    $request = $this->request->getCurrentRequest();
    $token = $this->container->get('security.token_storage')->getToken();

    if ($token === null || !($token->getUser() instanceof User)) {
        return;
    }

    $user = $token->getUser();
    $platform = $this->platform->getPlatform($request);
    $ip = $request->getClientIp();
    $date = new \DateTime('now');
    $url = $request->getUri();

    $log = new UserLog();
    $log->setUser($user);
    $log->setType($logType);
    $log->setPlatform($platform);
    $log->setIp($ip);
    $log->setDate($date);
    $log->setUrl($url);
    $log->setLogText($logText);

    $this->entityManager->persist($log);
    $this->entityManager->flush();
}
}
```

I logg actions in my controllers, for example when some UserAdmin try to edit another user i make something like this:

```
public function editUser(User $user, Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager)
{
    // First form for edit User //
    $userForm = $this->createForm(EditUserType::class, $user);
    $userForm->handleRequest($request);

    if ($userForm->isSubmitted() && $userForm->isValid()) {
        $entityManager->flush();
        $this->addFlash('notice', 'Profile has been edited');

        $logType = $this->logRepository->find(UserLogType::SUCCESS_ACTION);
        $this->userLogFactory->userLogFactory($logType, 'User edited user profile.');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('user_list');

    }
    elseif ($userForm->isSubmitted() && !$userForm->isValid()) {
        $logType = $this->logRepository->find(UserLogType::FAILED_ACTION);
        $this->userLogFactory->userLogFactory($logType, 'User has failed to edit user profile.');
    }
```

And there where is my problem, UserAdmin try to change User login for already existing in database i have that SQL error:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE user SET login = ? WHERE id = ?' with params ["aaa", 2]:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'aaa' for key 'UNIQ_8D93D649AA08CB10'
```

I have no idea what should i change to have normal form validation message eg. User with that login already exist.

I know that something is wrong with that UserLogFactory because without it everything works fine, but i can't determine the cause.

**EDIT**. Here is my User entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @UniqueEntity("login")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
public const ROLE_USER = 'ROLE_USER';

/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=10, unique=true)
 */
private $login;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\UserPermissionList")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_permisions")
 */
private $permissions;

ETC.
```

Comment: Paste your entity. It seems you have login property as unique field

Comment: @AythaNzt I edited my post to show entity, yes property Login is unique

Comment: @AythaNzt Exactly elseif statment is a problem, without it validation works fine but i need to logg every faild actions of User

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit 2** Ok, i figured out how to solve my problem, i just used [Form Model Class](https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/symfony-forms/form-dto) exactly like in the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
@UniqueEntity("login")
```

which mean that you cant have 2 rows with same value in login column. In this case

> An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE user SET login = ? WHERE
>   id = ?' with params ["aaa", 2]: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint
>   violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'aaa' for key 'UNIQ_8D93D649AA08CB10'

it is meaning that you have another row in User table with 'aaa' value in login column already

**EDIT**:

Add this:

```
@UniqueEntity(fields="login", message="This login already exist")
```

Comment: Yes, i know it, my problem is that i have this SQL error and i want normal message in form which tell UserAdmin about existing Login

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't work for me, i stil have screen with SQL error